# Java and sql loop optimization

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, loops, query-optimization

I'm grabbing a ResultSet from a database of people and ordering them by last names. I also have a table of other people that relate to that other table but since I can't figure out a way to order the second table by the order of ids in the first, I'm forced to execute a statement referring to the current id each time in the loop.

I'm positive the sql statement being executed in the loop through each iteration is what's slowing things down.

Slow code with reoccurring sql statement in loop

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
int id;
String phone;
for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
    rs.next();
    String name;
    id = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
    String middleInitial = rs.getString(3);
    if (middleInitial == null){
        name = rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(4);
    }
    else
        name = rs.getString(2) + " " + middleInitial + " " + rs.getString(4);
    sql = "select parent1mobilephone, parent1workphone from tblParent where id = " + id;
    rs2 = st2.executeQuery(sql);
    rs2.next();
    phone = rs2.getString(1).length() == 12 ? rs2.getString(1) : rs2.getString(2);
    rs2.close();
    DirectoryBoxesPanel.add(new DirectoryBoxes(name, id, phone, selection));    
}
endTime = System.nanoTime();
duration = (endTime - startTime);
System.out.println("For LOOP: " + duration/1000000L);
```

Faster unfinished code

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
int id;
String phone;
sql = "select parent1mobilephone, parent1workphone from tblParent ORDER by FIRST TABLE";
rs2 = st2.executeQuery(sql);
for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
    rs.next();
    String name;
    id = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
    String middleInitial = rs.getString(3);
    if (middleInitial == null){
        name = rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(4);
    }
    else
        name = rs.getString(2) + " " + middleInitial + " " + rs.getString(4);
    rs2.next();
    phone = rs2.getString(1).length() == 12 ? rs2.getString(1) : rs2.getString(2);
    DirectoryBoxesPanel.add(new DirectoryBoxes(name, id, phone, selection));    
}
endTime = System.nanoTime();
duration = (endTime - startTime);
System.out.println("For LOOP: " + duration/1000000L);
```

The only other way I can think of making this faster would be putting the two tables together in one but I don't know if I want to resort to that yet.

Comment: Er, use an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: If you need to check the data of the first table with data of another one, the select that data of the over table and put them in a hashmap (id as the key) asking a hashmap for a key is faster then asking the db.

Comment: Could you should us the table structure of the two tables and the foreign keys (if any)?

Comment: At the very very least, show us the code (with the SQL statement) that produces `ResultSet rs`. Preferably also table structures for the table(s) used in that ResultSet and table `tblParent`. With just the code above nobody can help you. Please `edit` your question (grey text below the tags) with this information.

Comment: if client speed is important, then you should definitely cache the data which won't require read queries on the DB.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks that did the trick! Didn't know you could do that

Comment: Use the appropriate join. But possibly you can use order by in your query to make you loop from order O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your `ResultSet rs` is based on a SQL statement that goes like this (fully groping in the dark here due to total lack of detail in the question):

```
sql = "select id, first_name, middle_initial, last_name from tblStudents";
```

Your code would become **MUCH** faster if you retrieve the details from `tblParent` in that same query, like (again, going blind on the table structure):

```
sql = "select s.id, s.first_name, s.middle_initial, s.last_name " +
      "       p.parent1mobilephone, parent1workphone " +
      "from tblStudents s join tblParents p on p.student_id = s.id " +
      "order by s.last_name";
```

Your Java code then becomes a simple loop over the `ResultSet`:

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
rs = ...;
while rs.next() {
    integer id = rs.getInt(1));
    String middleInitial = rs.getString(3);
    if (middleInitial == null) {
        String name = rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(4);
    } else {
        String name = rs.getString(2) + " " + middleInitial + " " + rs.getString(4);
    }
    String phone = rs.getString(5).length() == 12 ? rs.getString(5) : rs.getString(6);
    DirectoryBoxesPanel.add(new DirectoryBoxes(name, id, phone, selection));    
}
endTime = System.nanoTime();
duration = (endTime - startTime);
System.out.println("For LOOP: " + duration/1000000L);
```

Comment: Yep worked like a charm except I used inner join instead. select id, firstname, middleinitial, lastname, parent1mobilephone, parent2workphone from tblStudent inner join tblParent using(id) order by lastname. As far as the table structure, there's an id primary key on student and an id referencing student on the parent table. Thanks again